# Error upgrading Chef Server 12

Tags: chef-infra

I'm receiving the error below trying to upgrade to Chef Server 12 from Open Source Chef Server 11.

I've followed the instructions as per the docs here, https://docs.chef.io/upgrade_server.html#from-chef-server-osc

```
chef-server-ctl upgrade

Upgrading with options #<OpenStruct skip_confirmation=false, chef11_server_url="https://localhost", chef12_server_url="https://localhost", upload_threads=10, chef11_admin_client_name="admin", chef11_admin_client_key="/etc/chef-server/admin.pem">
Open source Chef 11 server detected.
Would you like to upgrade? [yN]
y
Upgrading the open source Chef 11 server.
Chef 12 short organization name? org
Chef 12 full organization name? ORG
Creating /tmp/chef11-server-data20151214-13790-jnzmtr as the location to save the open source Chef 11 server data
Ensuring Chef 12 server is stopped
ok: down: bookshelf: 0s, normally up
ok: down: nginx: 1s, normally up
ok: down: oc_bifrost: 142s, normally up
ok: down: oc_id: 140s, normally up
ok: down: opscode-chef-mover: 139s, normally up
ok: down: opscode-erchef: 139s, normally up
ok: down: opscode-expander: 137s, normally up
ok: down: opscode-expander-reindexer: 135s, normally up
ok: down: opscode-solr4: 135s, normally up
ok: down: postgresql: 1s, normally up, want up
ok: down: rabbitmq: 1s, normally up, want up
ok: down: redis_lb: 134s, normally up
Ensuring the open source Chef 11 server is started
ok: run: bookshelf: (pid 14115) 12s
ok: run: chef-expander: (pid 15585) 1s
ok: run: chef-server-webui: (pid 15760) 0s
ok: run: chef-solr: (pid 15654) 1s
ok: run: erchef: (pid 15703) 1s
ok: run: nginx: (pid 15426) 3s
ok: run: postgresql: (pid 15810) 0s
ok: run: rabbitmq: (pid 15765) 0s
Preparing knife to download data from the open source Chef 11 server
Writing knife config to /tmp/knife-config.rb for use in downloading open source Chef 11 server data
Downloading data from the open source Chef 11 server
Running knife download
ERROR: File /var/chef/cookbooks/var/chef is a directory while file /var/chef/cookbooks/var/chef is a regular file

Pulling open source Chef 11 database credentials
Finished downloading data from the open source Chef 11 server
Ensuring open source Chef 11 server is stopped
ok: down: bookshelf: 0s, normally up
ok: down: chef-expander: 0s, normally up
ok: down: chef-server-webui: 1s, normally up
ok: down: chef-solr: 0s, normally up
ok: down: erchef: 0s, normally up
ok: down: nginx: 0s, normally up
ok: down: postgresql: 0s, normally up
ok: down: rabbitmq: 0s, normally up
Open source Chef 11 server data downloaded to /tmp/chef11-server-data20151214-13790-jnzmtr
Created /tmp/chef12-server-data20151214-13790-3s5n0o as the location to save the tranformed data
Transforming open source Chef 11 server data for upload to Chef 12 server
/opt/opscode/embedded/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:1396:in `copy': unknown file type: /tmp/chef11-server-data20151214-13790-jnzmtr/users (RuntimeError)
    from /opt/opscode/embedded/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:469:in `block in copy_entry'
    from /opt/opscode/embedded/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:1506:in `call'
    from /opt/opscode/embedded/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:1506:in `wrap_traverse'
    from /opt/opscode/embedded/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:466:in `copy_entry'
    from /opt/opscode/embedded/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:441:in `block in cp_r'
    from /opt/opscode/embedded/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:1579:in `block in fu_each_src_dest'
    from /opt/opscode/embedded/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:1595:in `fu_each_src_dest0'
    from /opt/opscode/embedded/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:1577:in `fu_each_src_dest'
    from /opt/opscode/embedded/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:440:in `cp_r'
    from (eval):117:in `transform_chef11_data'
    from (eval):45:in `run_upgrade'
    from (eval):135:in `block in load_file'
    from /opt/opscode/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/omnibus-ctl-0.4.2/lib/omnibus-ctl.rb:190:in `call'
    from /opt/opscode/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/omnibus-ctl-0.4.2/lib/omnibus-ctl.rb:190:in `block in add_command_under_category'
    from /opt/opscode/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/omnibus-ctl-0.4.2/lib/omnibus-ctl.rb:661:in `run'
    from /opt/opscode/embedded/service/omnibus-ctl/chef-server-ctl:217:in `<main>'
```

Anybody know what the issue is here?

Answer (score 0):

I've found out that you can't upgrade to Chef Server 12 from a version lower than 11.1.0 using the normal method.

I upgraded to v 11.1.0 and then to 12.3.1 and it worked